# AngularJS - Initial value in text box is ignored when ng-model is present

Tags: html, angularjs

I have here a html text box. It has an `ng-model` and an initial value on it. The problem is the initial value is not shown when there's an ng-model present and I need both of the ng-model and the initial value for the textbox.

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
        ng-model="selPcode"
        name="missionId"
        value="123">
```

JS:

```
$scope.setPcode = function(site){
     $scope.selPcode = site.id};
```

Can anyone suggest a way how to make the value show in the text box and keep the `ng-model` present? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are python tags?

Answer (score 0):

Set an initial value to the ng-model on your controller's scope. Something like `$scope.selPcode = 123`. Set it to what your value would have been. That way, it'll display initially and then you can also change it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Angular works with [two-way data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04), so why not simply set the initial value in your controller?

```
$scope.selPcode = 123;
```

This way, you'll see it in your input.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need the `$scope.selPcode = site.id` and I want the initial value to be `123` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init without having to touch the controller and keep the code in the HTML readable, like you would with the value= syntax for the standard use of the Inputbox.   [Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aw1q4RYBo1JxOFBqoYgl?p=preview)

Example Here (Controller As Syntax):

```
<div ng-controller="myController as my">
  <h1>Hello {{my.name}}</h1>
  <input type="text"
    ng-init="my.selPcode=123"
    ng-model="my.selPcode"
    name="missionId">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  this.name = "Gene";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need the `$scope.selPcode = site.id` and I want the initial value to be `123` first.

Comment: So if site.id is null it should use 123?  If that is the case change the ng-init to "my.selPcode=(site.id || 123)"

Comment: i tried it but when I check the example at pluker, the initial vaue that is showing is 456.

Comment: Yes because I set it in the scope, via site.id.  Simply remove that setting.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it, can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the original question.  It's slightly unusual to need an input box to both have a value of 123 and another value of site.id via selPcode.  I suspect you might have a text box that has a display value and a real underlying value which you may want to store, e.g. the post code might be 12345 but in your db it has an id of usa-123?  You can do that internal to display representation in various methods.  One might be to listen for changes on the view model then set an internal scope id, in which case you wuoldn't attach it to the input value anyway.